# A formula for the number of order $2$ elements of $D_m\times D_n$ for even $m>2$ and odd $n>2$. (Gallian 8.24.)

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, finite-groups, dihedral-groups

This is Exercise 8.24 of Gallian's *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra (Eighth Edition)"*.

Answers that use material from the textbook prior to the exercise are preferred. Presentations, for instance, are not covered in the book so far; neither are semidirect products.

I have asked similar questions [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3125069/104041) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3131853/104041).

### The Question:

> Find a formula for the number of order $2$ elements of $D_m\times D_n$ for even $m>2$ and odd $n>2$.

Here $D_{r}$ has $2r$ elements and is defined as the symmetry group of the regular $r$-gon.

### Thoughts:

This is a task I think I should be able to do myself (if I had enough time).

I have yet to find a pattern.

Here is some GAP code I put together:

```
gap> for i in [2..5] do
> for j in [1..4] do
> m:=2*(2*i); n:=2*(2*j+1); S:=[];
> G:=DirectProduct(DihedralGroup(m), DihedralGroup(n));
> Print(m, ", ", n, "\n");
> for g in G do
> if Order(g)=2 then
> AddSet(S, g);
> fi;
> od;
> Print(Size(S), "\n");
> od;
> od;
8, 6
23
8, 10
35
8, 14
47
8, 18
59
12, 6
31
12, 10
47
12, 14
63
12, 18
79
16, 6
39
16, 10
59
16, 14
79
16, 18
99
20, 6
47
20, 10
71
20, 14
95
20, 18
119
gap>
```

(I'm sorry I'm dumping data on you like this . . . )

For clarity: the output is each pair $2m$, $2n$, followed immediately by the number of order $2$ elements in the respective group.

Please help :)

Comment: Do you know how to find the number of order $2$ elements of $D_k$?

Comment: If $(g,h) \in D_m \times D_n$ has order $2$ then either both $g$ and $h$ have order $2$ or $g$ is trivial and $h$ has order $2$ or $h$ is trivial and $g$ has order $2$. So you just need to figure out a way to count the number of involutions in a dihedral group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $f(k)$ denote the number of order $2$ elements of $D_k$. An element $(a,b)\in D_m\times D_n$ has order $2$ if and only if the least common multiple of the orders of $a$ and $b$ is $2$. That is, if either $a$ or $b$ has order $2$, or both. So the number of elements of order $2$ equals
$$f(m)+f(n)+f(m)\times f(n)=(f(m)+1)(f(n)+1)-1.$$
Of course $f(k)=k$ for odd $k$ and $f(k)=k+1$ for even $k$, so if $m$ is even and $n$ is odd, this becomes
$$mn+m+2n+1.$$